# Wrong referencing in The Legrand Book template

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

I'm using
[The Legrand Book Template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book). In chapter 3 I tried referring the placeholder image but it is not referring to it correctly as shown in image. 
[image]

```
\section{Figure}\index{Figure}
I'm referring to figure \ref{fig:placeholder}.
\begin{figure}[h]
\label{fig:placeholder}
\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{placeholder}
\caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}
```

You can find the complete code [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/pjvvdhcprfkn).

What should I do to correct it?

Comment: `\label` must appear after `\caption` (or in the `\caption{}` content), but not before. You're referring to the last counter being increased with `\refstepcounter`, this is `section` counter in this case (done internally in the `\section` macro, effectively), it uses the counter information from the `\section{Figure}` here, which is not what you want.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I only got **\label must appear after \caption, not before.** part of your comment. But it solved my problem so thank you. :)

Comment: The rest of my comment is the short explanation what happens ;-) By the way, this is a very frequent error and I think any good introductory book on LaTeX will say that `\label` should be used after `\caption` ;-)